# windows permissions vs ubuntu permissions

Tags: permissions

Opening some of my files in my usb drive from windows shows a message that reads as **"there was a problem sending a command to the program"**. I got that window for some files, only after I was accessing them from my ubuntu os. I have a question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/879030/resolving-there-was-a-pr%E2%97%8Cblem-sending-a-command-to-the-program?noredirect=1#comment1171497_879030) regarding it. Somebody suggested that the error may be because of the differences in the permission styles employed by windows and ubuntu.

And now, I need to know about the differences between the file/folder/partition permissions in windows and ubuntu. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

What are MS Windows/NTFS permissions and how they work:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx
http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/Understanding-Windows-NTFS-Permissions.html
Essentially:

1. access control list, saying "Allow" "read/write/execute/etc" for "some windows user or a group"
2. windows users are not identified by mere numbers, but have part of ID that is unique for particular Windows installation
3. permissions may be inherited from folder to subfolders and files

What are Linux file permissions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix)